# sql sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account error

Tags: sql, xp-cmdshell

when I run the following command in sql on ly local PC:

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'pc-name\my_username', 'password'
```

I'm getting the error:

> An error occurred during the execution of
>   sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. Possible reasons: the provided account
>   was invalid or the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential could
>   not be created. Error code: '5'.

This user I'm using when I login into windows and I'm logging to sql server(on my local pc) using windows authentication.

Should I create another user?

PS: from services, on SQL Service Agent Log On, I've set this user.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.msbicoe.com/post/2011/12/27/The-Problem-of-xp_cmdshell_proxy_account-credential-could-not-be-created.aspx

Right click, run As Administrator - to open your SQL Query Management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting Enterprise manager in elevated mode and running the command there?

As suggested in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/04/07/troubleshooting-sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-errors.aspx

Comment: I have licence only for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, I don't have installed Enterprise manager